# NextJS Typescript Layout complaining about missing props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Following the https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#with-typescript guide and modified my `Home` page that I want to use the layout on, as well as `_app.tsx`.

The guide didn't show what `Layout.tsx` should look like, and it's currently erroring with:

> Type '{ children: ReactElement<any, string |
> JSXElementConstructor>; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.   Type '{ children:
> ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>; }' is missing
> the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type,
> props ts(2322)

[image: error screenshot]

I'm new to TS and I'm not sure how to pass the page to Layout.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. I think it might be related to how you declare the prop as an argument to your functional component. Have you tried defining it as `export default function Layout(props : {children : ReactNode})`?

Comment: Also, to pass the page to layout, you add it within the Layout tag like this: `<Layout children={page}><Layout/>`. And to access it from within the Layout function you use `props.children`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you!  I would have never figured that out from the error message.  Do you have a resource you used to learn that?  Also if you put that as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages can be quite confusing.

Firstly, to pass the component `page` into the Layout component, you need to add an attribute within the `<Layout>` tag with the name of the prop, in this case "children" like this: `<Layout children={page}><Layout/>`. Check this source out for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Also, functional components only accept one "prop" object as parameter to the function, and it is an object containing the other attributes. Check out this page https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/ for more info.
Basically you need to rewrite the function definition to :

`export default function Layout (props : { children : string }) { ...`